# For a Linux nfs share, is it possible to forbid anonymous access?

Tags: nfs

Is it possible on Linux to forbid anonymous access to an nfs share?
Is a line like this in `/etc/exports`

```
/export                 192.168.0.0/24(rw,fsid=0,no_subtree_check,anonuid=99)
/export/share   192.168.0.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash,nohide,anonuid=99)
```

sufficient?

Note: 99 is the ***nobody*** uid on my system

Comment: You're using default (AUTH_SYS) authentication, right? Then you can't really deny access to anyone who is root on a client, because they can easily become any other uid.

Comment: Yes i know is not too safe the "sys" auth,i can use also KRB5P auth,but i want to know if is possible to forbid the anon user,even if root can change uid in a system